# So nice, we said it twice: "User is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct."

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, live-refresh, new-contributor-indicator

When I was leaving my second comment under a new contributor's post, I got a duplicate message:

[image]

> User is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct.

Sadly, the limit is two, no matter how many further comments you leave. Refreshing the page removes the second notice until you add another comment.

I also think I saw this on an answer where I hadn't previously commented, but I can't seem to reproduce that again.

Comment: just remove both of them.

Comment: This seems to be a regression. I just experienced it now as well; I'm sure it wasn't like this before.

Comment: @Karl any bug is a regression of some sort, something that used to work and suddenly got bugged and stopped working as expected. Only rarely something is bugged from the beginning, and then it's many times not even considered a bug, just something that was designed to work in a way many people will find wrong/odd.

Comment: Anyway I think the bugged part here is the live refresh, that reload comments after you post a comment, without having to reload the whole page.

Comment: Corresponding report on MSO: [Double "new contributor" message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426180/1478931)

Comment: @mar any juicy details about the fix? :)

Comment: There are no juicy details this time ;) When closing the dialog, we were making the template (the top one) visible. This way, when showing the form next time we were showing the notification twice (the message and the template both)...
This has been fixed in revision 2024.1.9.3159.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed in January 9<sup>th</sup> 2024, with the [following explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392049/so-nice-we-said-it-twice-user-is-a-new-contributor-be-nice-and-check-out-ou#comment1324423_392049) by Senior Software Developer marrados:

> When closing the dialog, we were making the template (the top one) visible. This way, when showing the form next time we were showing the notification twice (the message and the template both)... This has been fixed in revision 2024.1.9.3159.